# How can I structure a jQuery plugin that relies on other plugins, without forcing the user to link each one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin that leverages several smaller plugins. I do not want to force the user to have a separate script tag for each plugin. I could just throw them all in the same file, but it seems like there should be a better way.

The only idea I can come up with is to keep each plugin separate, but in a common folder. Within the main plugin, I would do something like the following:

```
if(!$.isFunction(pluginName){
     //load the plugin from common folder
}
```

Is there anything inherently wrong with this approach?

Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Bare in mind that many people will want to compress/minify their js to save some bytes before putting their site into production. Forcing them to use your import system might be annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try to create the  tag with the src and attach it to the document. This way you can "import" other js.

Something like this:

```
function importJs(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script"); //assuming that there is no lib yet, we do it manually
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

//and then we can do the imports
importJs("jquery.js");
importJs("somePath/someOtherLib.js");
//so on
```

This way, you can have just one file js that "import" and centralize any other js that you want to use.

For dynamic css import for example, you can do almost the same, but you change the script tag with the  tag, and instead of using src property for the path you use the href property, but you still have to set the type property, but for css mime: "text/css".

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something very similar to this.